# How to organize files in Git Repository

Tags: ios, xcode, git

I have a project that I've been working on for a while now and so far it has been just me working on it However, now someone new is about to join to help me with the project and I want to organize the files in my git repository. It's an iOS project. Right now the files are all over the place in the repo, but organized in Xcode. So for example, in Xcode there's the main project folder then there's three sub folders (i.e. Utilities, Main, Objects) and each folder has it's respective .h and .m files. But on my git repo on Github, the files are all over the place. If I try to create folders within the local repo directory and put the .h and .m files in there, the file names become red in Xcode. How can I organize my repo like it is in Xcode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Venmo has a great open source command line tool (called Synx) that might be just what you're looking for:
https://github.com/venmo/synx

Answer (score 0):

This has been a question I have dealt with in organizing iOS files/folders.

Once your project starts involving more than a few simple UIViews and images, yes, I think an organization structure is necessary. I have been a fan of folder references in XCode to keep organized. This way the XCode sidebar simply reflects your exact directory structure in Finder, as opposed to showing you all the files organized in your own fake yellow folders that don't actually correspond to real directories.

Here is great post to help you sort out references vs groups: http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2012/10/21/xcode-groups-vs-folder-references/

So yes, if you decide to change to using references, you will have to re-add all your files, and relink all your assets appropriately. The article talks about some downsides of doing this, but I haven't personally experienced them.

Keep in mind re-organizing all your files now might be a bit of work, but you will thank yourself in the long run!

---

The other way of doing it is to put all your files/assets in directories, delete the files in the sidebar in XCode, and then add the all again, thus updating their reference paths. Then you can manually create yellow folders (groups) to mimic your folder structure in Finder. But you will always have to remember to keep your structure updated since it doesn't happen automatically. The post above does a better job of explaining it.